# How to speed up inserting a CSV file into ClickHouseDB with JavaClient or JDBC

Tags: java, database, csv, jdbc, clickhouse

I want to insert a file with 864k rows ~ 100MB into a clickhouse Database. I know about ways to insert a file with ClickHouse Client or Importing staright from ClickHouse cloud - both this methods taking only about 1.5s to insert this file. My whole point is to insert a lot of csv files into database fast as possible.

I've tried to insert the same file with Java through different ways:

1. ClickHouse JDBC Driver:

```
 public void insertData(List<String> data) {
    try (PreparedStatement statement =
        connection.prepareStatement(
            "INSERT INTO btc_data SELECT * FROM input('col1 DateTime, col2 Float32, col3 Float32, "
                + "col4 Float32, col5 Float32, col6 Decimal(38,2), "
                + "col7 DateTime, col8 Float32, col9 Int32, col10 Decimal(38,2), "
                + "col11 Float32, col12 Int32')")) {

      batchInsertData(data, statement);

      statement.executeBatch();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  private void batchInsertData(List<String> data, PreparedStatement statement) {
    try {
      for (String str : data) {
        String[] values = str.split(",");

        LocalDateTime open_time =
            LocalDateTime.ofInstant(
                Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.parseLong(values[0])), ZoneOffset.UTC);
        LocalDateTime close_time =
            LocalDateTime.ofInstant(
                Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.parseLong(values[6])), ZoneOffset.UTC);

        statement.setObject(1, open_time);
        statement.setFloat(2, Float.parseFloat(values[1]));
        statement.setFloat(3, Float.parseFloat(values[2]));
        statement.setFloat(4, Float.parseFloat(values[3]));
        statement.setFloat(5, Float.parseFloat(values[4]));
        statement.setBigDecimal(6, new BigDecimal(values[5]));
        statement.setObject(7, close_time);
        statement.setFloat(8, Float.parseFloat(values[7]));
        statement.setInt(9, Integer.parseInt(values[8]));
        statement.setBigDecimal(10, new BigDecimal(values[9]));
        statement.setFloat(11, Float.parseFloat(values[10]));
        statement.setInt(12, Integer.parseInt(values[11]));

        statement.addBatch();
      }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
```

This one takes about **15 seconds - 10x times slower** to fully insert **100MB** file into a database.

2. JavaClient (I thought would be the fastest)

```
public void insertFromFile() {
    try (ClickHouseClient client = ClickHouseClient.newInstance(server.getProtocol())) {
      ClickHouseFile file =
          ClickHouseFile.of(
              "src/main/resources/864400.csv", ClickHouseCompression.NONE, ClickHouseFormat.CSV);
      ClickHouseResponse response =
          client
              .write(server)
              .set("format_csv_delimiter", ",")
              .table("btc_data")
              .data(file)
              .executeAndWait();
      ClickHouseResponseSummary summary = response.getSummary();
      System.out.println(summary.getWrittenRows());

      response.close();

    } catch (ClickHouseException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
```

This method takes about **28 seconds!!! - 20x times slower than native methods.**

**My overall question** is how to speed up inserting with Java so I could insert as fast as native methods with Clickhouse Client or Cloud, maybe just twice slower, but not 10x times slower.

I've tried RDBC Driver - too slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

full-disclosure: I work for ClickHouse and am not an expert with the Java clients. However, I discussed this with the Java dev team at ClickHouse. They made a couple of suggestions:

1. You may want to instrument some logging with timestamps to determine the amount of time being spent by Java bootstrapping vs. actual insertion time. This would provide a better comparison vs clickhouse-client
2. Adjusting the socket buffers for larger size can improve performance:

   prop.setProperty("buffer_size", "8192");

   prop.setProperty("socket_rcvbuf", "804800");

   prop.setProperty("socket_sndbuf", "804800");

Hope this helps - please let me know

Comment: Hello, Thom,   

About point 1, ```statement.executeBatch()``` taking about **13.5** seconds in Java with JDBC.   
Clickhouse Client inserting giving me a result after about **1.5** seconds.  
  
However, If I'm looking on query_logs for my insert query I can see clearly a column named thread_ids and there are only 2 threads used. Maybe I can use more threads somehow, but not sure how. max_inserts_threads set to 16.  
  
About point 2. Using this slowed down a little my query - from 13.5 seconds to 15.5 seconds, but this not too big to worry about.

Comment: max_insert_threads could help if there is a bottleneck in the threading at the server-side. However, since the speed with clickhouse-client is quite a bit faster, I'm not sure this is the bottleneck (and it looks like clickhouse server thinks it only needs 2 at that rate). At the Java client side, how many parallel insert connections and threads are you using? Parallelizing the client threads would likely increase insert rate, although would require splitting the CSV client-side. Will share your additional details with the Java dev team also, for more input

Comment: Yeah, I've checked logs for query from clickhouseClient and there are only 2 threads were used too - https://github.com/emelyanovkr/crypto-data-service-loader Source code. I had an idea about implementing multi inserting and splitting CSV five, but I haven't gotten round to this idea yet

Comment: Our #clickhouse-jdbc dev wanted to reply here but doesn't have enough rep. I'll copy/paste his answer here or can go to ClickHouse Community Slack #help channel and he happy to help further:  
Some facts on the JDBC Driver
* each insert in JDBC driver is single-threaded
* It looks JDBC layer is overheated. Not the best approach to insert a CSV 
* in the lower level of the driver, like used in the second example. Our CSV read is single-threaded
* The configuration options provided earlier should boost the performance (there are some internal buffers & socket buffers)

Comment: Also - In the query log, you may want to compare the insert time of both the clickhouse-client & java only from the query log point of view. Can query the system.query_log in various ways of course, but just providing an example here: SELECT query,* FROM system.query_log WHERE type = 'QueryFinish' AND query ILIKE '%INSERT%' ORDER BY query_duration_ms DESC LIMIT 10; #clickhouse-jdbc